# npm install Giving error when Moving Project to Another Directory

Tags: node.js, error-handling, npm, package.json, npm-install

I have a node project running in a directory, and I simply want to move it to another directory, let's say. When I try that, of course without the node_modules folder, and try to run npm install; it gives this error:

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/me_here
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3

npm ERR! No version provided in package.json
```

My package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "my-amazing-title",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "an amazing description",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "My full name",
  "license": "MIT",

  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.3.5",
    "express-react-views": "file:../../",
    "js-md5": "^0.4.0",
    "react": "^0.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.0",
    "request": "^2.69.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14"
  }
}
```

Comment: When you add "express-react-views": "file:../../", npm will look for a package.json in ../../ folder to install this dependency. Change this folder to a valid npm package folder or even a original [source](https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to npm install with your package.json by changing this line:

```
"express-react-views": "file:../../",
```

to

```
"express-react-views": "~0.10.0", //the current version at date of posting
```

Comment: or just "express-react-views": "latest",